# Navigaton strategy - drilldown on children - does not retain ordering in icCube

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

In the icCube Web Reporting you can set a graph and chart to respond on a click row/column/cell event and inidcate what must be done when the widget receives a click.

In this particular case I have the rows ordered based on a parameter.

But when I click on the row in the graph, the children are displayed without any order.

I found the following workaround, but it helps only with a named measure not a parameter:

- use navigation strategy MDX iso children and use:

  ORDER ($member.children, [measures].[amount], BASC)
- the following gives an MDX error:

  ORDER ($member.children, @{PARAMETER}, BASC)

The cause for the error is that it does not replace the @{PARAMETER} with the actual value.

[image: Visual explenation]

Is there any other way/workaround to get this working in icCube?

A live working example explaining the questiuon can be found [here](http://demo.inside-vision.nl/icCube/doc/ic3report?ic3demo&name=%2Fshared%2FStackOverflow%2FStack%20-%20order%20issue)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it's a limitation - bug - in the current version : http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-165

Will be fixed in 5.1.2